# facebook and twitter plugins position

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, twitter

I would like to know whether there is any problem if I use this two script in the same page:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" width="200" height="440" href="https://twitter.com/smth" data-    widget-id="347786415695880192"></a> 
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

and this one:

```
<a class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/smth/12345328620951" data-width="282" data-height="430" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></a>


<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Because they have the same variable's name and I have a problem: when I set the same position in the CSS file, they don't appear in the same coordinates. Actually, the facebook plugin position depends on the place where I write the  line, but I'm having some problems because this pugling (facebook) is moving all the page coordenates reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
style="width:282px; position:absolute; left:-162px;"
```

to `<a class="fb-like-box"...`

This will position the box vertically inline with the Twitter widget and then we pull it left so it doesn't appear over the magazine.

Comment: thanks for your answer! however, I tried to use <div> and I have the same problem: I think that the facebook plugin has a different positioning reference because its "top:0px" is different from that position for the twitter plugin and also it is moving the rest of elements in the page. Is there any part of the code that I can add to clarify my question? Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you link me to the page where this is all happening?

Comment: yes: hopesheffield.org I wanted to put the facebook plugin on the left side of the central image but then, a blank space appears at the end of the page. thanks!

Comment: Could you put the Facebook widget into the page somewhere even if it breaks please?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the solution, let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: oh wow!! brilliant!! :) thank you very much for your help and fast respond!!! :) :)